# node.js unzip cannot find or open

Tags: javascript, node.js, unzip, child-process

Basically, I'm in Node.js, and I want to call unzip on a simple zip file. So I'm using the following code:

```
  var cmd = 'unzip -o -d "'+dst+'" "'+file+'"';
  console.log(cmd);
  child_process.exec(cmd, function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  });
```

But, when, when I run the content of variable "cmd" in the shell:

```
unzip -o -d "/tmp/uncompressedDirectory" "/tmp/someSettings.zip"
```

it runs perfectly. But when I execute that piece of code, I get this:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: unzip:  cannot find or open /tmp/someSettings.zip, /tmp/someSettings.zip.zip or /tmp/someSettings.zip.ZIP.
I20141208-15:35:36.123(-8)?    ] killed: false, code: 9, signal: null }
```

What is so different between the these two? I'm expecting child_process to produce the exact same result as the one I'm running in the shell.

[EDIT 1]

I'm actually using Meteor, and I'm importing child_process with Npm.require("child_process").

[EDIT 2]

I also tried with:

```
child_process.spawn("unzip", [ "-o", "-d", dst, file ]);
```

And after attaching events for "exit" and "error", the exit one is called with the code == 9.

Comment: Check file and directory permissions. Most probably the file is not available to the process spawned by node.

Comment: everyone can read the file. But I'll take a look tomorrow a bit more if I can force CollectionFS to give different permission to the uploaded files.

Comment: why not use the npm package [unzip](https://www.npmjs.org/package/unzip) -- it'll be way more efficient than spawning a child process